Migration from Spring 5 to Spring 6: Issue with `springSecurityFilterChain`
I am currently migrating a Spring JSF application from Spring 5 to the latest Spring 6. I am using Java 17 with spring-boot-starter-parent version 3.3.5 and Spring Security version 6.3.4.
In the previous version, we had the following configuration in web.xml for the springSecurityFilterChain:
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

We are now converting this configuration to Java-based configuration using Spring Boot. Here is the corresponding Bean definition in our WebConfig class:
@Bean 
public FilterRegistrationBean<DelegatingFilterProxy> springSecurityFilterChain() { 
    FilterRegistrationBean<DelegatingFilterProxy> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
    registrationBean.setFilter(new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain"));
    registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("*.jsf", "*.jsp"); 
    return registrationBean;
} 

However, I am encountering the following error during application startup:
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Could not convert argument value of type [java.util.ArrayList] to required type [java.util.List]: Failed to convert value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type 'java.util.List'; Cannot convert value of type 'org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean' to required type 'jakarta.servlet.Filter': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:757) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:237) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1375) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1212) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:313) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:971) ~[spring-context-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625) ~[spring-context-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) [spring-boot-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) [spring-boot-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) [spring-boot-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]

It seems like Spring is trying to convert a FilterRegistrationBean to a jakarta.servlet.Filter, which is causing the issue.
Question:
How can I correctly define the springSecurityFilterChain Bean in Spring 6 to avoid this conversion error?
Additional Information:

Java version: 17
Spring Boot version: 3.3.5
Spring Security version: 6.3.4

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

You should leave the web.xml configuration as is and do not attempt to create a springSecurityFilterChain in the Spring application context. DelegatingFilterProxy must be in the Servlet container's filter chain to forward HTTP requests to Spring.

Spring provides a Filter implementation named DelegatingFilterProxy that allows bridging between the Servlet container’s lifecycle and Spring’s ApplicationContext. The Servlet container allows registering Filter instances by using its own standards, but it is not aware of Spring-defined Beans. You can register DelegatingFilterProxy through the standard Servlet container mechanisms but delegate all the work to a Spring Bean that implements Filter.


